# Find a finite set vector that their span is $\mathbb{R}^d$

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, vector-spaces

Assume that $A:X \to GL(d, \mathbb{R})$ be a continuous function on a compact metric space $X$. Assume that there are a non-zero $u \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and a compact set $Y\subset X$ such that $\operatorname{span}\{A(x)u: x\in Y\}=\mathbb{R}^d$.

Is it true that we can find $(v_1, \ldots, v_{d})$ such that $v_i=A(x_i)u$ for $x_i \in Y$, $1\leq i \leq d$ and $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_d\}=\mathbb{R}^d?$ I think that is true as we are working on the finite case.

Sorry, if the question is simple. I want to make sure that my impression is correct.

Comment: Can you edit the question to make the math formulas readable?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why continuity or compactness are needed; they just clutter the picture.

If you assume the spanning condition, then you merely choose $x_1$ so that $A(x_1)u\ne 0$, $x_2$ so that $A(x_1)u, A(x_2)u$ are linearly independent, and continue. This is just the usual argument that there is a basis for a finite-dimensional vector space. Since you know the given set spans $\Bbb R^d$, you are guaranteed to be able to proceed at each step.

Comment: Thank you very much. One more question, it is true that there is $y \in Y$ such that the angle between $A(y)u$ and $\operatorname{span}\{v_1, \ldots, v_d\}$ is bounded away zero?

Comment: This is impossible. The span is all of $\Bbb R^d$.

Comment: Thanks! So, the answer to the following one is also negative? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4530633/angle-between-a-vector-and-the-span

Comment: The last question, is it true that there is a $x$ such that the angle between $A(x)u$ and $u$ is bounded?